# Difference between $|x| \leq q < 1$ and $|x| < 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

When studying the uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$, I found that this two constraints on $x$, $|x| \leq q < 1$ and $|x| < 1$, affect the uniform convergence of the series ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ uniformly converges when $|x| \leq q < 1$ but not when $|x| < 1$). Then I conclude that that two constraints must not be the same thing.

I can vaguely explain the difference by describing that $x$ such that $|x| < 1$ can take any values as close to $1$ as it can, otherwise with $|x| \leq q < 1$, $x$ is bounded by this value $q < 1$, i.e. can't be as freely as it can to be near 1.

But then when reading about power series, I'm confused by these two theorems, in particular conditions of $x$:

> For any power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, there exists a non-negative number $R$ ($R = 0$ and $R = \infty$ are included as special [extreme] cases) called the radius of convergence of the series such that:
>
> (c) if $R_1$ is any number for which $0 < R_1 < R$ then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges uniformly for all $x \in [-R_1, R_1]$.

> If the power series $F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ has radius of convergence $R$, then for any numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $-R < a < b < R$, $\int_a^b F(x) dx$ exists. Moreover, $$\int_a^b F(x)dx = \int_a^b \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_a^b  a_n x^n dx.$$

The theorem on integrability of power series above, as my material noted and I don't agree, was restated for power series from this theorem:

> If the sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a, b]$ then for each $x \in [a, b]$: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_a^x f_n(t) dt = \int_a^x \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  f_n(t) dt. $$

If my understanding about the difference between $|x| \leq q < 1$ and $|x| < 1$ was right then, there must be a gap between the second and the third theorem (as in the order presented here). By the first and the third theorem, $a$ and $b$ in the second satisfy that $- R_1 \leq a < b \leq R_1$, not $-R < a < b < R$.

I don't think that the material I used was wrong about any of these. Hope that you folks can help correct me if I was misunderstood anything, or close the gap between the second and the third theorem.

Comment: $|x|\leq q < 1$ means that $1-|x|$ has a positive lower bound of $1-q>0$ while $|x|<1$ means the lower bound might be $0$.

Comment: Why do you believe there is a gap between the second and third theorems? The third theorem is about uniform convergence on closed intervals $[a,b]$, and the first tells you that a power series converges uniformly on all closed intervals in $(-R,R)$. The second theorem is then simply applying the third theorem to these closed intervals.

Comment: The ranges of $x$ are $[-q,q]\subset(-1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ respectively. Hence the supremums are $q$ and $1$.

Comment: @Servaes It comes from the way I think that $a$ and $b$ should be picked from $[-R_1, R_1]$ rather than $(-R, R)$ since $[-R_1, R_1] \subset (-R, R)$. The thing about closed intervals you said seems to help me get this correctly.

Comment: I'm glad the different phrasing helps. Note that picking $a$ and $b$ from $[-R_1,R_1]$ or from $(-R,R)$ makes no difference; for any $a,b\in(-R,R)$ we can take $R_1=\operatorname{max}(|a|,|b|)$, which satisfies $0<R_1<R$, and then we have $a,b\in[-R_1,R_1]$.

Comment: @Servaes What about picking $x$ from $[-q, q]$ or from $(-1, 1)$? It would affect the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The first theorem does not tell you that the power series converges uniformly for all $x\in[-R,R]$. It tells you that the power series converges uniformly for all $x\in[-R_1,R_1]$, for every value of $R_1$ with $0<R_1<R$.

Moving to the second theorem; it follows that for any two numbers $a$ and $b$ with $-R<a<b<R$, the series converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, and so by the third theorem you have the identity
$$\int_a^b F(x)dx = \int_a^b \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_a^b  a_n x^n dx.$$
This identity may fail if $a=-R$ or $b=R$, as then the series may not converge uniformly.